# Macro stops running on opening a new workbook (xlsm format)

Tags: excel, vba

The VBA macro stops running on opening certain workbooks. When I run the code in break mode, it seems like control goes over to the newly opened workbook and there it has no instructions to follow.

I am trying to open a lot of workbooks, take a printout and close them.

I have also tried opening them in Read only mode, setting the calculation mode to manual but nothing has worked so far.

Comment: Could you include the code you are using?

Comment: I have always found that executing a `Workbooks.Open` statement immediately jumps out of single-step mode in VBE - it's as if I had pressed F5.  But that doesn't mean the macro stops.  Rather it means that the macro runs to the end.  (I usually just include a breakpoint after the `Open` statement so that I get control back.)

Comment: Sub Openfile()
    Workbooks.Open (FilePath), UpdateLinks:=False
End Sub

Answer (score 0):

The following will work if you have a folder with all the workbooks.
This code will iterate through a series of excel files in a given folder:

```
Dim objFSO As Object
Dim objFolder As Object
Dim objFile As Object
Dim strPath As String
Dim intLen As Integer
Dim strName As String
Dim wsSheet As Worksheet

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

strPath = "C:\Users\username\Desktop\FolderName" 'Set path of folder with excel files
Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(strPath) 'Get the folder object associated with the directory
For Each objFile In objFolder.Files 'Loop through the files in the folder
    Workbooks.Open (strPath & "\" & objFile.Name)
  Set wsSheet = Worksheets("Sheet1") 'Name of sheet in excel file

  ActiveWorkbook.CheckCompatibility = False 'Skip compatibility check
```

This code will printout a pdf of the specified range on each sheet to a given path:

```
intLen = Len(objFile.Name) - 5 'Remove .xlsx characters from name
strName = Left(objFile.Name, intLen)
wsSheet.Range("A1:P58").ExportAsFixedFormat xlTypePDF, "C:\Users\username\Desktop\" & strName & ".pdf", , , , , , False
```

This code will close each file without saving and continue the loop through the folder:

```
    Workbooks(strName).Close SaveChanges:=False 'Close excel file without saving

Next
```

Comment: Yes... I use the below code to open the workbook
Sub Openfile()
    Workbooks.Open (FilePath), UpdateLinks:=False
End Sub

Comment: I made edits to my answer. Let me know if it works out.